# Load Image in JAVA FX

Tags: java, image, javafx

im trying to load image from file system, but i have no error and don't display image. THe file of the image is in the Package folder ../src/application/a.png , i try to load image in different way like this:

Image image = new Image("file:a.png");

Image image = new Image(new File("a.png").toURI().toString());

```
package application;

import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        Image image = new Image(new File("/a.png").toURI().toString());
        // Setting the image view
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        // Setting the position of the image
        imageView.setX(0);
        imageView.setY(0);
        // setting the fit height and width of the image view
        imageView.setFitHeight(200);
        imageView.setFitWidth(400);
        // Setting the preserve ratio of the image view
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);



        // Creating a Group object
        Group root = new Group(imageView);

        // Creating a scene object
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 300);
        // Setting title to the Stage
        stage.setTitle("Coloradjust effect example");
        // Adding scene to the stage
        stage.setScene(scene);

        // Displaying the contents of the stage
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

If the image you are trying to load is in the same directory as your class, try:

image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("a.png")).

Else, if it is in a sub-directory of the directory your class belongs to, try:

image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("application/a.png")).
Given that your project structure is:

|----src

|----Main

|--------application

|--------a.png